# Different User, friendships and selection

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
User:

+----+----------+--+
|    |   User   |  |
+----+----------+--+
| pk | email    |  |
|    | password |  |
|    | ...      |  |
+----+----------+--+

and Friendship:

+----+-------------+--+
|    | FriendShip  |  |
+----+-------------+--+
| pk | user1_email |  |
| pk | user2_email |  |
|    | date        |  |
|    | accepted    |  |
+----+-------------+--+
```

So basically, when someone wants to befriend someone else, we record it in the friendship table.

Let's say now that we want to select all the user with less than 3 friends, it is easy to that except for people who does not have friends because there is no record of that in the `friendship` table.

My query looks like this for the moment:

```
SELECT u.email, COUNT(u.email) 
FROM user u 
    INNER JOIN friendship f ON f.user1_email = u.email OR f.user2_email = u.email
GROUP BY u.email 
HAVING COUNT(u.email) < 3;
```

How can I add the result of the asocial people :p?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a UNION to quickly get what you want.

```
SELECT u.email, COUNT(u.email) 
FROM user u 
INNER JOIN friendship f ON f.user1_email = u.email OR f.user2_email = u.email 
GROUP BY u.email 
HAVING COUNT(u.email) < 3
UNION
SELECT u.email, 0
FROM user u
WHERE u.email not in (SELECT user1_email from friendship) 
AND u.email not in (SELECT user2_email from friendship);
```

Comment: Yes this is pretty quick and is working fine, but let's  say now that we want to set dynamically the born, like from 0 to 3 friend or 1 to 7. This won't work because the fact to check if he has 0 friend is like hardcoded

Comment: Your question clearly states you want to know how many people have 0 to 3 friends.   Your question does not mention anything about being able to query for an arbitrary number of friends.  If you have another question, I suggest you post it.